# Android Biometric hit FINGERPRINT_ERROR_LOCKOUT how to reset without waiting 30seconds

Tags: android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

Android 6.0 above, not using Samsung library. Using android-google biometric library, when user hit maximum attempts it will throw FINGERPRINT_ERROR_LOCKOUT.

I know that after 30seconds user is allow to try login using biometrics again, but I want to know is there any way I can do to avoid waiting 30 seconds? As in I can manually reset it so that user can try login using biometric again without waiting the 30 seconds countdown.

I have searched on internet, most of the solution is wait until 30 seconds finished then let user to try biometric login again.

For start listening, I call mFingerprintManager.authenticate(), for cancelling I call mCancellationSignal.cancel(), it doesn't work if its status is still under FINGERPRINT_ERROR_LOCKOUT (30seconds wait time), I want to know what way I can bypass and reset so I do not have to wait for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't override the countdown - this is a requirement mandated by the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd), specifically, section [7.3.10.1 C-1-5](https://source.android.com/compatibility/9/android-9-cdd.html#7_3_10_1_fingerprint_sensors):

> - [C-1-5] MUST rate limit attempts for at least 30 seconds after five false trials for fingerprint verification.

Comment: I have seen one of the existing banking app in Google Playstore, when it hits Max limit of Attempts, which is FINGERPRINT_ERROR_LOCKOUT. 

It redirect user to its Phone lock mode (Pattern/Pincode) when user key-in the correct phone lock Pin code , it straight continue to the biometric screen and there is no more 30 seconds.

I think there is a way to override the countdown or so called reset, because the above app i mention, when user failed 5 times of biometric attempt, it direct user to key in lock screen mode pincode, the biometric 30 seconds is gone after correct PIN-Code is entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can either wait for the user to enter their password on lockscreen, or you can use the [`BiometricPrompt#setDeviceCredentialAllowed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder.html#setDeviceCredentialAllowed(boolean)) API to request pin/pattern/password.

The Android Framework resets lockout when a valid pin/pattern/password is entered.

The API is available on the framework Q and older, but is available on the `androidx.biometric` library for all APIs where lockscreen/biometric is supported.

The deprecated method for requesting device credentials is `KeyguardManager#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()`, checking for `RESULT_OK` in `startActivityForResult`